# Problem to reassign a value to an existing batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm struggling with this little annoyance in a batch file:

This is beginning the code:

```
SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF "%CAMFORLARGEPARTS%" EQU "NO" (SET REGISTRYFILEPARTSIZES=Normal_Parts) ELSE (SET REGISTRYFILEPARTSIZES=Large_Parts)
SET PROMPTFORPARTSIZE=YES
```

Down the road, we have this as well, in the same .cmd file

I am trying, without success, to reassign a different value to %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%

```
:ASKABOUTPARTSIZE
ECHO OFF
IF "%PROMPTFORPARTSIZE%" NEQ "YES" GOTO SKIPTHIS

CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "USE LARGE PARTS? -> PRESS 'Y' FOR YES | 'N' FOR NO"
ECHO ON
ECHO.
ECHO THE ERRORLEVEL VALUE RETURNED BY CHOICE.EXE IS %ERRORLEVEL%

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
ECHO.
ECHO THE VALUE SET FOR VARIABLE CAMFORLARGEPARTS IS %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%

PAUSE

EXIT

:SKIPTHIS
...
```

These are the results I'm getting. I don't understand why even receiving and passing the correct errorlevel based on the user
s input, I'm alkways getting %CAMFORLARGEPARTS% set as YES.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Thanks a million!

Comment: You should evaluate the errorlevel from the `choice` command, not the `echo` command!

Comment: The kneejerk response here is `reverse the order of evaluation of errorlevel`, but doing that actually INVOKES the problem. As published, all I can say is that "it works for me". I simply duplicated the `choice..ECHO THE VALUE` lines and responded y/n and n/y and the value set was correct. I also removed the `echo`es between the `choice lines` and `if errorlevel` lines, with the same result.

Comment: @Compo, `echo` does not set `errorlevel`.

Comment: @Magoo, descending order is meant specifically in cases where multiple errorlevels are returned and you use goto. It cannot pass down to the lower errorlevels as you then break away from the if statements once the highest match is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon my commented advice, here's an example which doesn't change your structure too much.

```sh
:ASKABOUTPARTSIZE
@ECHO OFF
IF /I NOT "%PROMPTFORPARTSIZE%" == "YES" GOTO SKIPTHIS

%SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32\CHOICE.EXE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "USE LARGE PARTS? -> PRESS 'Y' FOR YES | 'N' FOR NO"
SET "CHOICECODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"

ECHO(
ECHO THE ERRORLEVEL VALUE RETURNED BY CHOICE.EXE IS %CHOICECODE%

IF %CHOICECODE% EQU 2 (SET "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO") ELSE SET "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES"

ECHO(
ECHO THE VALUE SET FOR VARIABLE CAMFORLARGEPARTS IS %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%

PAUSE

EXIT /B

:SKIPTHIS
…
```

Comment: In commenting out the code to share and adding code to debug it, I introduced more problems. I'm using this as my reference: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php - Evaluating the errorlevel directly don't solve the issue.

Comment: @DanielSantos, I have absolutely no intention of visiting another website to read things you may or may not have included within your question proper. My code above was carefully designed to work with the code you posted, and should output the correct information as a result. I am not here to guess what else you may have excluded or to answer multiple questions within one. Please replace your code above with that I've offered, try it, and see that it correctly reflects the variable values you wanted in your question.

Comment: I think I understand what I was doing wrong: commands between choice and if, like ECHO, return an ERROLEVEL of 0 too, and that spoils the flow. Is that a correct assemement? Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @DanielSantos `echo` does not set errorlevel. Open `cmd` type `ping gsspd` which will set `errorlevel` to 1. No type `echo Test` then `echo %errorlevel%`

Comment: @DanielSantos. *Some*, in fact *most* commands will alter `errorlevel`. `ECHO` and `SET` do ***NOT*** change `errorlevel`. Actually, your original code as posted works for me.

Comment: @Compo The link to another website was for Joe because he said I had to use % around errorlevel... and I have not.

Comment: @Magoo the reason why the code works for you is because of both `if` statements are true. So if you chose `N` it will set it to `YES` then set to `NO`, it is not ideal but it will work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

As you `choice` command has only 2 options, a simple method is to use an `else` statement and only evaluate `errorlevel 2`

It is important to not have ANY other commands between `choice` and `if errorlevel`

```
@echo off
CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "USE LARGE PARTS? -> PRESS 'Y' FOR YES | 'N' FOR NO"

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    SET "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO"
) else (
    set "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES"
)
echo %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%
```

Alternatively you can still evaluate each `errorlevel` and simply use `goto` statements. This has to be in descending order else it will not work:

```
@echo off
CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "USE LARGE PARTS? -> PRESS 'Y' FOR YES | 'N' FOR NO"

If ERRORLEVEL 2 goto :CAM2
If ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :CAM1
If ERRORLEVEL 0 exit /b
goto :EOF  
:CAM2
SET "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO"
goto :result
:CAM1
SET "CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES"
:result
echo %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%
```

Comment: Thank you so much for setting me in the correct direction... I can see where I was wrong now!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly not an answer, since there's no problem with the original code as posted.

Code tested:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
cls

ECHO.&ECHO --- As posted --- but with ECHO turned off

CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "Use Large Parts? -> Press 'Y' for Yes | 'N' for No
ECHO.
ECHO The errorlevel value returned by choice.exe is %ERRORLEVEL%

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
ECHO.
ECHO The value set for variable CAMFORLARGEPARTS is %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%
CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "Use Large Parts? -> Press 'Y' for Yes | 'N' for No
ECHO.
ECHO The errorlevel value returned by choice.exe is %ERRORLEVEL%

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
ECHO.
ECHO The value set for variable CAMFORLARGEPARTS is %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%

echo.&ECHO --- As posted but testing directly after choice

CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "Use Large Parts? -> Press 'Y' for Yes | 'N' for No
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
ECHO.
ECHO The value set for variable CAMFORLARGEPARTS is %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%
CHOICE /C YN /N /T 10 /D Y /M "Use Large Parts? -> Press 'Y' for Yes | 'N' for No

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
ECHO.
ECHO The value set for variable CAMFORLARGEPARTS is %CAMFORLARGEPARTS%

echo.&ECHO Now testing ERRORLEVEL changes with intervening ECHO

call :seterr 8
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%
echo.&ECHO But testing ERRORLEVEL changes with intervening CALL ECHO
CALL ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %%errorlevel%%
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%
echo.&ECHO But testing ERRORLEVEL changes with intervening different CALL ECHO
call :seterr 7
CALL ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%

echo.&ECHO Now testing ERRORLEVEL changes with intervening SET

call :seterr 6
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%
SET zz=61
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%

echo.&ECHO Now testing ERRORLEVEL changes with intervening SET /A

call :seterr 5
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%
SET /a zz=616
ECHO ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%

PAUSE
GOTO :eof

:seterr
EXIT /B%1
```

Result:

[image: Test results]

So there appears to be something wrong with OP's test scenario...and I think I see it.

The code manipulates and displays `CAMFORLARGEPARTS` but the display shown is of `SOLIDCAMFORLARGEPARTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=YES
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 SET CAMFORLARGEPARTS=NO
```

`IF ERRORLEVEL 1` checks if the `ERRORLEVEL` is equal to `1` OR greater than one, this is problematic because if `ERRORLEVEL` is `2` then that will also be greater than one.